# Client/Server Application - Server Side not receiving data

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I am trying to create a simple client/server application. Very basic - Client connects to server, client sends message to server - server receives message and broadcasts to any other connected clients.

As I say - it is supposed to be simple and for the purpose of self teaching better understanding.

As far as I can tell, the client is sending the data and I believe the difficulty is in the server receiving the data packets. Would anyone mind letting me know if there is something blindingly obviously wrong with my code.

Many thanks in advance.

Client

```
Imports System.Net ' for IPAddress
Imports System.Net.Sockets 'for TcpListener
Imports System.Text


Module testClient
''' <summary>
''' CLIENT
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Sub Main()
    Dim aString As String
    Dim port As Integer
    Dim localAddr As IPAddress
    Dim client As TcpClient
    Dim stream As NetworkStream
    Dim tempSocket
    Try
        port = 2302
        localAddr = IPAddress.Loopback
        Do
            Console.Write("are you ready to connect to your server? (y/n) ")
            aString = Console.ReadLine()


        Loop Until aString = "y" Or aString = "n"


        Do
            If aString = "y" Then
                'Create a TcpClient.
                client = New TcpClient(localAddr.ToString, port)
                Console.Write(" Connencted to : " & IPAddress.Parse(CType(client.Client.LocalEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address.ToString).ToString & " ")


            End If
            Console.Write("Ready to quit? (y/n)")
            aString = Console.ReadLine()
            If aString <> "y" Or aString <> "n" Then
                'this is where we send a message to the server
                Dim endPoint As New IPEndPoint(localAddr, port)
                tempSocket = New Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
                tempSocket.Connect(endPoint)
                stream = New NetworkStream(tempSocket)
                Dim outStream As Byte() = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(aString)
                stream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Count)
                stream.Flush()
            End If
        Loop Until aString = "y"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write(ex.ToString)
    End Try


End Sub


End Module
```

Server:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text


Module testServer
Dim port As Integer
Dim localAddr As IPAddress
Dim server As TcpListener
Dim client As TcpClient
Dim bytesFrom As Byte()
''' <summary>
''' Server
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Dim tempSocket
Sub Main()


    Try
        port = 2302
        localAddr = IPAddress.Loopback


        server = New TcpListener(localAddr, port)




        server.Start()
        Console.WriteLine("Server ready")



        client = server.AcceptTcpClient
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to " & IPAddress.Parse(CType(client.Client.LocalEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address.ToString).ToString)


        getmessage()




    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub


Sub getmessage()


    Dim endPoint As New IPEndPoint(localAddr, port)
    Dim clientSocket As New TcpClient
    Try


        clientSocket.Connect(endPoint)
        Dim Stream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
        Stream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Count)
        Dim dataFromClient As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
        dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
        printOut(dataFromClient)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        clientSocket.Close()
    End Try


End Sub
Sub printOut(msg As String)
    Console.WriteLine(msg)
End Sub


End Module
```

Comment: What about WCF - much simpler to set up and the socket is done for you.

Comment: Do you have any resources pertaining to this? -Cheers

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19752/WCF-WPF-Chat-Application)

Comment: Thank you - i'll dig in my brain for the C# memories